# trac python bindings messed up

Tags: python, svn, centos, trac

My trac and svn used to work it still does if i click on the links many times. How ever it complains of he following and i am not sure what to do I have followed http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion and http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion but nothing's changed. I am using centos 5, svn 1.6, trac 0.10.4, python 2.4.3

```
2013-11-29 14:24:14,458 Trac[main] ERROR: Unsupported version control system "svn". Check that the Python bindings for "svn" are correctly installed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/web/main.py", line 406, in dispatch_request
    dispatcher.dispatch(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/web/main.py", line 191, in dispatch
    chosen_handler = self._pre_process_request(req, chosen_handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/web/main.py", line 263, in _pre_process_request
    chosen_handler = f.pre_process_request(req, chosen_handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/versioncontrol/api.py", line 73, in pre_process_request
    self.get_repository(req.authname).sync()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/versioncontrol/api.py", line 91, in get_repository
    raise TracError('Unsupported version control system "%s". '
TracError: Unsupported version control system "svn". Check that the Python bindings for "svn" are correctly installed.
2013-11-29 14:24:15,090 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading file plugin ez_setup from /usr/share/trac/plugins/ez_setup.py
2013-11-29 14:24:15,154 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.ticket.web_ui from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,286 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.ticket.query from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,345 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.attachment from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,345 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.versioncontrol.svn_fs from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,564 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin tracopt.mimeview.enscript from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,627 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.mimeview.patch from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,629 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.mimeview.txtl from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,643 Trac[loader] WARNING: Cannot load plugin trac.mimeview.txtl because it requires "textile>=2.0"
2013-11-29 14:24:15,643 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.admin.web_ui from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,644 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.admin.web_ui from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named admin.web_ui
2013-11-29 14:24:15,682 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.web.session from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,683 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.ticket.admin from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,684 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.ticket.admin from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named admin
2013-11-29 14:24:15,685 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.mimeview.rst from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,699 Trac[loader] WARNING: Cannot load plugin trac.mimeview.rst because it requires "docutils>=0.3"
2013-11-29 14:24:15,699 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.db.postgres from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,701 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.versioncontrol.web_ui from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,734 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.timeline from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,735 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.timeline from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named timeline.web_ui
2013-11-29 14:24:15,736 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.mimeview.pygments from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,749 Trac[loader] WARNING: Cannot load plugin trac.mimeview.pygments because it requires "Pygments>=0.6"
2013-11-29 14:24:15,750 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.wiki.admin from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,750 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.wiki.admin from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named admin
2013-11-29 14:24:15,751 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.about from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,752 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.about from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named about
2013-11-29 14:24:15,752 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin tracopt.ticket.commit_updater from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,758 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin tracopt.ticket.commit_updater from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/tracopt/ticket/commit_updater.py", line 48, in ?
ImportError: No module named compat
2013-11-29 14:24:15,759 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.wiki.interwiki from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,762 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.ticket.roadmap from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,765 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.versioncontrol.svn_prop from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,766 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.versioncontrol.svn_prop from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named svn_prop
2013-11-29 14:24:15,766 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.mimeview.silvercity from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,779 Trac[loader] WARNING: Cannot load plugin trac.mimeview.silvercity because it requires "SilverCity>=0.9.4"
2013-11-29 14:24:15,779 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.wiki.macros from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,780 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.db.sqlite from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:15,790 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin tracopt.ticket.deleter from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,045 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin tracopt.ticket.deleter from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/tracopt/ticket/deleter.py", line 22, in ?
ImportError: No module named translation
2013-11-29 14:24:16,046 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.wiki.web_ui from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,054 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin tracopt.mimeview.php from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,055 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.web.auth from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,090 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.wiki.web_api from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,091 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.wiki.web_api from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named web_api
2013-11-29 14:24:16,092 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.admin.console from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,092 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.admin.console from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named admin.console
2013-11-29 14:24:16,093 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.db.mysql from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,094 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin tracopt.perm.authz_policy from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,096 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin tracopt.perm.authz_policy from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/tracopt/perm/authz_policy.py", line 23, in ?
ImportError: cannot import name IPermissionPolicy
2013-11-29 14:24:16,097 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.versioncontrol.svn_authz from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,097 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.versioncontrol.admin from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,098 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.versioncontrol.admin from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named admin
2013-11-29 14:24:16,098 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.search from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,099 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.search from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named search.web_ui
2013-11-29 14:24:16,099 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin tracopt.perm.config_perm_provider from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,100 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.prefs from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
2013-11-29 14:24:16,101 Trac[loader] ERROR: Failed to load plugin trac.prefs from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/trac/loader.py", line 101, in load_components
    entry_point.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named prefs.web_ui
2013-11-29 14:24:16,101 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading egg plugin trac.ticket.report from /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
```

I have tried import. is the following normal?

```
[root@hero trac]# python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Mar 14 2007, 18:51:08) 
[GCC 4.1.1 20070105 (Red Hat 4.1.1-52)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from svn import core
>>>
```

I get the following

```
[root@hero trac]# trac-admin nagios initenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/trac-admin", line 21, in ?
    from trac.scripts.admin import run
ImportError: No module named scripts.admin
```

I have now done the following which has fixed issue of allowing me to create trac projects, however I cannot get into trac using browser.

```
[root@hero trac]# easy_install -m trac
Searching for trac
Best match: Trac 0.12
Processing Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg
Removing Trac 0.12 from easy-install.pth file
Installing trac-admin script to /usr/bin
Installing tracd script to /usr/bin

Using /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg

Because this distribution was installed --multi-version, before you can
import modules from this package in an application, you will need to
'import pkg_resources' and then use a 'require()' call similar to one of
these examples, in order to select the desired version:

    pkg_resources.require("Trac")  # latest installed version
    pkg_resources.require("Trac==0.12")  # this exact version
    pkg_resources.require("Trac>=0.12")  # this version or higher

Processing dependencies for trac
Finished processing dependencies for trac
```

The error I receive is

```
[Mon Dec 02 10:58:21 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.85] PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend: Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://hero/trac/
[Mon Dec 02 10:58:21 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.85] PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend:   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 287, in HandlerDispatch\n    log=debug), referer: http://hero/trac/
[Mon Dec 02 10:58:21 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.85] PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend:   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 461, in import_module\n    f, p, d = imp.find_module(parts[i], path), referer: http://hero/trac/
[Mon Dec 02 10:58:21 2013] [error] [client 172.16.0.85] PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend: ImportError: No module named trac, referer: http://hero/trac/
```

Comment: You are running Trac 0.12, which can be seen in the egg that is loaded: `Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg`. Did you try the steps at http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion#Checklist? It is also concerning that several other modules are not loading.

Comment: i tried to upgrade to trac 0.12 but did not work from 0.10.4

Comment: I would check your web server configuration files next. Note also that [ModPython](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModPython) is deprecated.